# Remove trailing zeros along with a case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've been trying to remove the trailing zeros from a column of a table. When I use a case statement (to remove the zeros when a flag is turned on, and to keep them when a flag is turned off) it doesn't work properly. It doesn't recognize the flag. @Tim Biegeleisen has helped me explain the implicit conversion that was happening though.

I want to remove or retain the zeros interchangeably. When the flag is on for example, I would like 0.091000 be 0.091; and when the flag is off, I want it be the same 0.091000. For example, this works properly to retrieve removing the zeros and retaining the zeros separately.

```
CREATE TABLE #tablea 
(item CHAR(2), name VARCHAR(10), amount DECIMAL(9,2)) 

INSERT INTO #tablea 
VALUES ('AB', 'D1', 1.10), 
       ('AB', 'D2', 1.00), 
       ('AB', 'D3', 0.90), 
       ('AB', 'D4', 0.09)    

SELECT  CAST(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS VARCHAR(max)), cast(CAST(amount 
AS decimal(6,2)) as float)  
FROM #tablea
```

It displays two columns: one with the zeros and one without the zeros.

However, it doesn't remove the zeros at all in a table. It doesn't recognize the flag at all. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @flag INT = 1

SELECT CASE WHEN @flag = 1 
THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS VARCHAR(max))
ELSE amount END 
FROM #tablea
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server in conjunction with a programming language such as Java, PHP, or C#?  If so, then consider handling this requirement in your presentation layer.

Comment: Is it impossible to handle it on SQL Server? I was just wondering.

Comment: The thing is, your requirement is still a bit vague (at least to me).  If you are starting off with a numeric type, then conceptually there are no trailing zeroes, so it's a moot point.  If you have a _string_, then there may be trailing zeroes, but you already have a few good ways of removing them if you don't want them.

Comment: I want the user decide to keep them or remove them. There is a flag. If the flag = 1, then I want them be removed; if the flag = 0, I want them be kept. For example, let's say the amount is 0.0900. If the flag = 1, I want it be 0.09. If the flag = 0, I want it be 0.0900 itself. Got it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression will always return a value of the same data type, according to the [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). In your case, considering a branch is returning a `varchar` and the other one is returning a `decimal`, the result will always be a `decimal`.

To get the desired results, change the `CASE` expression to return the same data type in both branches:

```
DECLARE @flag INT = 1

SELECT CASE WHEN @flag = 1 
THEN CAST(CAST(amount AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS VARCHAR(100))
ELSE CAST(CAST(amount AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR(100)) END 
FROM #tablea
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way...

```
    CREATE TABLE #tablea (item CHAR(2), name VARCHAR(10), amount decimal(18,6), flag int) 

    INSERT INTO #tablea 
    VALUES ('AB', 'D1', 1.10, 1), 
           ('AB', 'D2', 1.00, 0), 
           ('AB', 'D3', 0.90, 1), 
           ('AB', 'D4', 0.09, 0)    

    SELECT case when  flag = 1 then FORMAT(amount, 'n2') else FORMAT(amount, 'n4')  end amt FROM #tablea
```